# Is there a way to determine the size of an array based on t

Tags: c, arrays, size

I wrote a function that calculates outer differences between an array and this array itself, and only saves those results that are positive (see code below)

```
void outer_pos(double *x, int *n, double *output){
    int i, j, l;
    for(i=0, l=0; i<*n; i++){
        for(j=0; j<*n; j++){
            if((x[j]-x[i])>0){
                output[l+1]=x[j]-x[i];
                output[0]=(double)(++l);
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Then, in the function below, I call `outer_pos`. One issue is that the array xouter may contain tied values. Without tied values, the number of positive differences is (*nsamp)*(*nsamp-1)/2, but with tied values, the actual number is smaller. So I wonder if there is any way to declare v1v2 such that the size depends on the result from `outer_pos`. I primarily use R, which doesn't require that you initialize an array, so I am not sure how this can be done in C.

```
void foo(double *x, double *y, int *nsamp){
    int i, j, k, oper=2, l;
    double* result=malloc(sizeof(double)*((*nsamp)*(*nsamp-1)/2 + 1));
    double* xouter=malloc(sizeof(double)*(*nsamp));

    for(i=0;i<*nsamp;i++) 
         xouter[i]=x[i]+y[i];

    outer_pos(xouter, nsamp, &result[0]);

    free(xouter);    
        .
        .
        .
        .
}
```

Comment: The C code with malloc should work. What is the result?

Comment: Do you mean what the result of `outer_pos` is? Basically I mean I want `v1v2` to be of the size `l` (note the counter in `outer_pos`). If there are tied values, then `l` would be smaller than `*nsamp*(*nsamp-1)/2`. But at this point I basically declare the length of v1v2 as `*nsamp*(*nsamp-1)/2` regardless of the actual size it needs to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. try calloc() instead of malloc and alloc memory for output inside the outer_pos()

   ```
   void outer_pos(double *x, int *n, double *output){
       int i, j, l;
       &output[0]=malloc(sizeeof(double));
       for(i=0, l=0; i<*n; i++){
           for(j=0; j<*n; j++){
               if((x[j]-x[i])>0){
                   &output[l+1]=malloc(sizeeof(double));
                   output[l+1]=x[j]-x[i];
                   output[0]=(double)(++l);
               }
           } 
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: What do I need to do inside `foo()`? In other words, how should I declare `v1v2`?